# Checking for Palindrome in Assbembly MASM

Tags: assembly, masm

This function takes an input string and checks if it's a palindrome or not. It breaks however due to a memory error. I've been staring at it for a few hours but can't figure out the problem. There many unnecessary pushes but I am scared to play with it and break even more. Would appreciate any help.

```
__declspec(naked)
int isPalindrome(char *input_string, int left_index, int right_index)
{

// C code to be converted to x86 assembly
/*
    // Input Validation
    if (NULL == input_string || left_index < 0 || right_index < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    // Recursion termination condition
    if (left_index >= right_index)
        return 1;
    if (input_string[left_index] == input_string[right_index]){
        return isPalindrome(input_string, left_index + 1, right_index - 1);
    }
    return -1;
*/

__asm{

        mov eax, 0
        // BEGIN YOUR CODE HERE

        push ebp
        push edi
        mov ebp, esp;

        mov ebx, input_string
        mov esi, [ebp+12]
        mov edi, [ebp+16]
        //push edi;
        push esi;
        push ebx;

        // mov some_register, [esp + 8]


        mov ebx, input_string
       // mov esi, left_index  // esi
            // mov esi, [esp + 8]
        mov edi, right_index // edi
        cmp esi, 0;
        jl FALSE;
        cmp edi, 0
        jl FALSE
        cmp ebx, 0x00
        je FALSE

        cmp esi, edi
        jge TRUE


        mov cl, byte ptr[ebx + esi]
        mov dl, byte ptr[ebx + edi]
        cmp cl, dl 
        je RECURSIVE
            jmp FALSE

    RECURSIVE:

        inc esi 
        dec edi
        push eax
        push ecx
        push edx

        push esi
        push edi
        call isPalindrome
        //sub ebp, 8
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop edx
            jmp END
    FALSE:

        mov eax, -1
        jmp END

    TRUE:

        mov eax, 1
        jmp END
    END:
        pop ebx;
        pop esi;
        pop edi;


        mov esp, ebp;
        pop ebp;


        // END YOUR CODE HERE
        ret
}
```

}

Comment: so if you give it string "abba", what values you see in registers in the second call depth? If I'm reading the code correctly, already the second depth mush have almost every argument value wrong (plus after returning back the upper level will probably fail to return). You don't need to "stare" at it, run it in debugger instruction by instruction, with paper+pen at desk, writing down notes about values in registers, and comparing them with expectations and definitions of data.

Comment: Yes the problem is that the function gets called with the old arguments, the left and right index don't get updated in the reclusive call.

Comment: That's simply not true. Upon entering the function first time the `left_index` is at address `esp+8`, which will result for example to 0x0150. On the second level of recursion the `left_index` is again at `esp+8`, but after evaluating this is not pointing to `0x0150` any more, so you don't get old arguments. You may get wrong arguments, but the "old" is still sitting at `0x0150` in memory. So start paying attention to `esp` value, and open also memory window to watch content of stack, how it evolves. (BTW, many debuggers have specialized view just for stack, making it nicely up-to-date)

Comment: That said, you should fetch the string pointer from arguments too, so `mov ebx, input_string` is cheating, unless the compiler is magic enough to treat it as local argument and compile it as `[ebp+x]` (verify in listing file or disassembly in debugger) ... (in such case you can use it also for other arguments, not sure why you mix those, use rather just one style, this is confusing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues here. 
Firstly, I must say that I don't think this problem is a good candidate for a recursive solution as supplying it with a large string could result in (dare I say it) stack overflow, and the recursion is just unnessesary.

Looking at your proc the same way it is attempting to look at the string, the first issue I see is with your preamble/epilogue:

```
push ebp
push edi
mov ebp, esp
```

does not match with:

```
pop edi
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

You will end up with ebp = your original edi, then try to return to the original ebp address (crash). Obviously either 'pop edi' should be after 'mov esp, ebp', or more likely you want 'push edi' after 'mov ebp, esp'

As the inclusion of edi in these stands out to me as being very non-standard, I assume you have added it in an attempt to support your recurrsion, and suggest that this is not helpful.

For the proc, you start off with:

```
mov ebx, input_string
mov esi, [ebp+12]
mov edi, [ebp+16]
```

at this point your stack looks like:

```
[esp+00]  edi value
[esp+04]  original ebp value
[esp+08]  return address
[esp+12]  *input_string
[esp+16]  left_index
[esp+20]  right_index
```

( and obviously you have set ebp=esp )

assuming you are trying to get the two index values into esi and edi, these are not where they were as you have added a 'push edi' before storing esp in ebp.

Soon afterwards you have:

```
mov ebx, input_string
mov edi, right_index
```

and there is also a commented out 'mov esi, left_index'

If your compiler supports the tracking of procedure arguments by name, you are better off using them rather than [ebp+xx] which is what such references will usually be complied to, however it seems odd that you would be hand coding your prelude/exit code if this were the case. Have you cut&pasted disassembler output here? If so then you should not be including:

```
; prelude
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

; exit
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
;          ( or possibly 'leave' which does the same thing )
```

The ASM starts with 'mov eax, 0' which would seem to suggest that your default return value is 0, however the ASM seems to be trying to return 1 for true or -1 for false. In 32 bit assembly -1 = 0xFFFFFFFF which in a standard boolean test would equate to 'TRUE'.

I would assume that this code should be returning '0' not '-1' for false. Perhaps '-1' is being used as an error code for a NULL pointer etc.

all that being said, I *think* this is what you're looking for:

```
  push edi
  push esi
  push ebx
  push edx

  mov ebx, input_string
  mov esi, left_index
  mov edi, right_index

  // - ERROR -
  mov eax, -1 

  cmp ebx,0
jbe pEND
  cmp esi,0
jb pEND
  cmp edi,0
jb pEND

  // - FALSE -
  mov eax, 0  

  cmp esi, edi
  jge pTRUE

mov dl, byte ptr[ebx + edi]
cmp dl, byte ptr[ebx + esi]

  jne pEND

// RECURSIVE

inc esi 
dec edi

push edi
push esi
push ebx
call isPalindrome

  jmp pEND

  pTRUE:
mov eax, 1

  pEND:
  pop edx
  pop ebx
  pop esi
  pop edi

  ret
```

and declare it using __stdcall instead of __declspec(naked)